# Orchard FullCalendar Module - Add/Edit Event

Tags: c#, jquery, fullcalendar, orchardcms

I'm trying to make a booking system for Orchard by using the jQuery FullCalendar ([Link to the jQuery FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)). 
I found this [youtube tutorial on how to install FullCalendar as a Widget in Orchard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv7rA-viyTw&list=PL0-GOAU3tpMYm0F1CHYP5_egk0mmAGMab) and got it setup in 1.7.2 after a while.
Now I would like to be able to add and edit events from the site (currently it's setup so you have to add new events through the admin panel, same with editting).

I think the place where I have to start could be in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dPKW5Xjr).

When I use the following code:

```
//dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

            //    if (allDay) {
            //        alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
            //    }else{
            //        alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
            //    }

            //    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

            //    alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
            //},
```

And then click on a time on my calendar it tells me the date and so on (so the onclick event works), I'm just not sure how I should move on from that.
I would like to be able to just add an event from the calendar view atm. So far I have been able to add it, but not to save it to the database, I suppose it has something to do with:

```
var fullCalEvents = [];
var iterator = function (event) {
     var newEvent;
     newEvent = new Booking.Event(event.title, event.start, event.end, event.url, false);
     fullCalEvents.push(newEvent);
                                };
```

But I'm not sure where to start.

The current select I have written is the one where I can add an event, but not save it in the database.

I can provide more information if need be!

I hope someone can enlighten me on how to do this.

Thank you

Casper

Comment: Hello LeCattez can you show your "select:" callback from fullcalendar, please?

In fullCalEvents array if i were you i would add simple JSON objects to it then you could use that array and add it to Fullcalendar eventSources...

Comment: Hello. I don't have anything besides that "select" in the pastebin. I was just using it to try it out. All it does is add an event until refresh, which is why I need it to save it to the database. 
I'm just a little confused on how to do that.

Comment: Sorry i missed the pastebin, well if you want to book an event, client side, and save in DB already, i would fetch the event properties in select call back, like you are doing now and pass that values in a AJAX call to the server, saving it to DB after success callback in AJAX call refresh the calendar to fetch your eventSources. If you need an example let me know.

Comment: Hey again. An example would be nice. I have googled a little and saw some people use an AJAX call, but I wasn't sure how I would set up the connection the right way.

Comment: I might add that I'm currently just using the build-in database in Visual Studio atm.

Answer (score 0):

Lets give a try LeCattez,

I do not mess around with C# for a while, but you might know what i'm going to talk about.
In your handler class you will need to have something like this, this is from another question here in SO.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler 
{
   public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext ctx) 
   {
       var json = new JSONResonse()
       {
           Success = ctx.Request.QueryString["name"] != null,
           Name = ctx.Request.QueryString["name"]
       };

       ctx.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
       ctx.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerialzeObject(json));
}

   public bool IsReusable {
       get { return false; }
   }
}
```

In your handler you must fetch data sent from AJAX call. This is an example on how you can send data with Jquery.Ajax.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view){


 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',                       
    url: ajaxcallURL(_url,"2001"),                  
    data: {"start":start,"end":end,"allDay":allDay },       //Here you can send data to server
    beforeSend:function(){
      //TODO do somethin before sendind data
    },
    complete:function(){
        calendar.fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ); //This line will force hte calendar to re-get all eventSources
        //wich means everytime you select a time period in calendar this will happen
    },                          
    success: function(data) 
    {   
        //TODO Do stuff with eventual data you need to send back to client
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //Handle errors here                    
    }
}); 

},//SELECT
```

Offcourse you can send to server an object, example an JSON object and fetch that object there like the example you see above.

No in the http Handler you will have to save to DB data.

Did you understood? Or you need further explanation? Let me know...

Comment: Do I need so much code to save it to the database? I can't save it in the same way as it's saved in the admin panel? (not that I have anything against the above, it just seems to be a large piece of code for something I thought could be more simple).

I'm still not so sure what my AJAX url would be, haven't really been working with that in this project (just been using the database in visual studio and nhibernation via. Orchard).
Oh and of course, thanks for helping!

Comment: Well you just need the AJAX call part you can somehow with your framework get the request from the AJAX call...The url is the path to your projet Http request handler, but that will need to be you to figure it out....and come on this is the simplest has it gets man :P

If you need more explanation let me know.